# The "import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions; " and import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber; cannot be resolved to a type error

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, pom.xml

[CucumberError in test runner class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QG7pg.png)

While trying to add the packages
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
in the test runner class I am getting the error(s)
"The import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions cannot be resolved",
"The import cucumber.api.junit cannot be resolved"

Below is the code:

```
package testRunners;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "Feature"
        ,glue={"stepDefinition"}
        )
public class SearchTestRunner {

}
```

The pom.xml is as given below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>nopCommerceV002_Cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>nopCommerceV002_Cucumber</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>nopCommerceV002_Cucumber</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

   <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.8.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-bom</artifactId>
                <version>7.2.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <!-- Work around. Surefire does not include enough
                             information to disambiguate between different
                             examples and scenarios. -->
                        <configurationParameters>
                            cucumber.junit-platform.naming-strategy=long
                        </configurationParameters>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't mention the version for cucumber in your pom, it is using the most latest version.

Since version 4.5.0 the package `cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber` has moved to `io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber` and package `cucumber.api.CucumberOptions` has moved to `io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions`

Either change your import statement or specify a version older than 4.5.0 in your pom(Won't recommend it as version 4.4.0 was released in 2019).

For cucumber changelogs see [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: Hi...I tried by importing the packages io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber and io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions but still getting the same error-"Import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber cannot be resolved" and "io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions cannot be resolved"

Comment: What version of cucumber are you using? Did you build and reload your project?

Comment: Try adding cucumber-junit dependency to your pom.
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

Comment: Asif your answer is almost right. But this project is using JUnit 5, not JUnit 4. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine#configuration-options

Comment: Thanks Asif and Korstanje. The issue is resolved now. I have added the following dependencies  and plugins and it worked. <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.3</version>
</dependency><dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Thank. I you can solve it with the following dependencies and imports.

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

<dependency> 
<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId> 
<artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId> 
<version>7.2.3</version> 
</dependency>

<dependency> 

<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId> 
<artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId> 
<version>7.2.3</version> 
<scope>test</scope> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).